# What are those RSA Challenges, DES Challenges and RSA Factoring Challenges

Tags: rsa, des, brute-force-attack, factoring

Can someone explain the differences between the DES challenge, the RSA challenges, and the RSA factoring challenge? What were the aims?
I think the factoring challenge was to encourage research, the DES challenge was to show that 56-bit keys are too short. But how do the three challenges relate to each other?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.SE. What did you search? And what is not clear from [RSA Factoring Challenge = RSA challenges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_Factoring_Challenge)  and [DES Challanges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DES_Challenges) All started by the RSA Resaerch?

Comment: what were the different aims of the three different challenges? according to Wikipedia the factoring challenge ran from 1991 to 2007, the RSA Secret-Key Challenge from 1997 to 2007 and the DES challenge from 1997 to 1999. The factoring challenge is clear: decompose semi-primes. What exactly did the other challenges demand?

Comment: It is all written in Wikipedia: `The DES Challenges were a series of brute force attack contests created by RSA Security to highlight the lack of security provided by the Data Encryption Standard.`

Comment: okay, understood. and the factoring challenge was supposed to find faster algorithms. What was the RSA Secret Key challenge?

Comment: The top of it all. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_Secret-Key_Challenge

Comment: thanks kelalaka. So, were the DES challenges based on 56-bit keys? Or on what length? The wikipedia article is pretty thin on what the challenge actually was and what tools were used for encryption.

Answer (score 1):

**RSA labs set up [Cryptographic Challenges](https://web.archive.org/web/20170417095542/https://www.emc.com/emc-plus/rsa-labs/historical/cryptographic-challenges.htm)<sup>*</sup>**

All bolds are mine!

> Various cryptographic challenges — including the RSA Factoring Challenge — served in the early days of commercial cryptography **to measure the state of progress in practical cryptanalysis and reward researchers for the new knowledge they have brought to the community**. Now that the industry has a considerably more advanced understanding of the cryptanalytic strength of common symmetric-key and public-key algorithms, these challenges are no longer active. The records, however, are presented here for reference by interested cryptographers.

- [RSA Laboratories’ secret-key challenges](https://web.archive.org/web/20170417095446/https://www.emc.com/emc-plus/rsa-labs/historical/the-rsa-laboratories-secret-key-challenge.htm)

  > **The goal of RSA Laboratories’ secret-key challenges was to quantify the security offered by the government-endorsed data encryption standard (DES) and other secret-key ciphers with keys of various sizes.** The information obtained from these contests was of value to researchers and developers alike as they estimated the strength of algorithm sor applications against exhaustive key-search.
- **[The RSA Factoring Challenge](https://web.archive.org/web/20170417091951/https://www.emc.com/emc-plus/rsa-labs/historical/the-rsa-factoring-challenge.htm)**

  > The RSA Challenge numbers are the kind we believe to be the hardest to factor; these numbers should be particularly challenging. These are the kind of numbers used in devising secure RSA cryptosystems.

  On the other hand, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DES_Challenges) provides better then currently archive RSA web page

  > The DES Challenges were a series of brute force attack contests created by RSA Security to **highlight the lack of security provided by the Data Encryption Standard.**

We have a question about on the details of DES challanges of RSA

- [In the RSA DES challenges, how did the contestants know they had found the right key considering they weren't given any plaintext?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/64863/18298)

---

<sup>*</sup> RSA labs purchased by EMC and all of the RSA links come from archives.

Comment: If I'm missing something, could you let me know?